# Генерация картинок в цикле

Tags: php

Есть код — создание штрих кода. Как сделать чтобы генерировались картинки в таблицу? 
[image: Таблица]

```
$arr = array('34234234', '234234234234', '342342342');
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
    $filepath = "";
    $size = "20"; 
    $orientation = "horizontal";
    $code_type = "code128";
    $print = false; 
    $sizefactor = "1";
    $text = $value;
}
// This function call can be copied into your project and can be made 
// from anywhere in your code
barcode($filepath, $text, $size, $orientation, $code_type, $print, $sizefactor);

function barcode($filepath="", $text="0", $size="20", $orientation="horizontal", $code_type="code128", $print=false, $SizeFactor=1 ) {
    $code_string = "";
    // Translate the $text into barcode the correct $code_type
    if (in_array(strtolower($code_type), array("code128", "code128b")) ) {
        $chksum = 104;
        // Must not change order of array elements as the checksum depends on the array's key to validate final code
        $code_array = array(" "=>"212222","!"=>"222122","\""=>"222221","#"=>"121223","$"=>"121322","%"=>"131222","&"=>"122213","'"=>"122312","("=>"132212",")"=>"221213","*"=>"221312","+"=>"231212",","=>"112232","-"=>"122132","."=>"122231","/"=>"113222","0"=>"123122","1"=>"123221","2"=>"223211","3"=>"221132","4"=>"221231","5"=>"213212","6"=>"223112","7"=>"312131","8"=>"311222","9"=>"321122",":"=>"321221",";"=>"312212","<"=>"322112","="=>"322211",">"=>"212123","?"=>"212321","@"=>"232121","A"=>"111323","B"=>"131123","C"=>"131321","D"=>"112313","E"=>"132113","F"=>"132311","G"=>"211313","H"=>"231113","I"=>"231311","J"=>"112133","K"=>"112331","L"=>"132131","M"=>"113123","N"=>"113321","O"=>"133121","P"=>"313121","Q"=>"211331","R"=>"231131","S"=>"213113","T"=>"213311","U"=>"213131","V"=>"311123","W"=>"311321","X"=>"331121","Y"=>"312113","Z"=>"312311","["=>"332111","\\"=>"314111","]"=>"221411","^"=>"431111","_"=>"111224","\`"=>"111422","a"=>"121124","b"=>"121421","c"=>"141122","d"=>"141221","e"=>"112214","f"=>"112412","g"=>"122114","h"=>"122411","i"=>"142112","j"=>"142211","k"=>"241211","l"=>"221114","m"=>"413111","n"=>"241112","o"=>"134111","p"=>"111242","q"=>"121142","r"=>"121241","s"=>"114212","t"=>"124112","u"=>"124211","v"=>"411212","w"=>"421112","x"=>"421211","y"=>"212141","z"=>"214121","{"=>"412121","|"=>"111143","}"=>"111341","~"=>"131141","DEL"=>"114113","FNC 3"=>"114311","FNC 2"=>"411113","SHIFT"=>"411311","CODE C"=>"113141","FNC 4"=>"114131","CODE A"=>"311141","FNC 1"=>"411131","Start A"=>"211412","Start B"=>"211214","Start C"=>"211232","Stop"=>"2331112");
        $code_keys = array_keys($code_array);
        $code_values = array_flip($code_keys);
        for ($X = 1; $X <= strlen($text); $X++) {
            $activeKey = substr( $text, ($X-1), 1);
            $code_string .= $code_array[$activeKey];
            $chksum=($chksum + ($code_values[$activeKey] * $X));
        }
        $code_string .= $code_array[$code_keys[($chksum - (intval($chksum / 103) * 103))]];

        $code_string = "211214" . $code_string . "2331112";
    } elseif (strtolower($code_type) == "code128a") {
        $chksum = 103;
        $text = strtoupper($text); // Code 128A doesn't support lower case
        // Must not change order of array elements as the checksum depends on the array's key to validate final code
        $code_array = array(" "=>"212222","!"=>"222122","\""=>"222221","#"=>"121223","$"=>"121322","%"=>"131222","&"=>"122213","'"=>"122312","("=>"132212",")"=>"221213","*"=>"221312","+"=>"231212",","=>"112232","-"=>"122132","."=>"122231","/"=>"113222","0"=>"123122","1"=>"123221","2"=>"223211","3"=>"221132","4"=>"221231","5"=>"213212","6"=>"223112","7"=>"312131","8"=>"311222","9"=>"321122",":"=>"321221",";"=>"312212","<"=>"322112","="=>"322211",">"=>"212123","?"=>"212321","@"=>"232121","A"=>"111323","B"=>"131123","C"=>"131321","D"=>"112313","E"=>"132113","F"=>"132311","G"=>"211313","H"=>"231113","I"=>"231311","J"=>"112133","K"=>"112331","L"=>"132131","M"=>"113123","N"=>"113321","O"=>"133121","P"=>"313121","Q"=>"211331","R"=>"231131","S"=>"213113","T"=>"213311","U"=>"213131","V"=>"311123","W"=>"311321","X"=>"331121","Y"=>"312113","Z"=>"312311","["=>"332111","\\"=>"314111","]"=>"221411","^"=>"431111","_"=>"111224","NUL"=>"111422","SOH"=>"121124","STX"=>"121421","ETX"=>"141122","EOT"=>"141221","ENQ"=>"112214","ACK"=>"112412","BEL"=>"122114","BS"=>"122411","HT"=>"142112","LF"=>"142211","VT"=>"241211","FF"=>"221114","CR"=>"413111","SO"=>"241112","SI"=>"134111","DLE"=>"111242","DC1"=>"121142","DC2"=>"121241","DC3"=>"114212","DC4"=>"124112","NAK"=>"124211","SYN"=>"411212","ETB"=>"421112","CAN"=>"421211","EM"=>"212141","SUB"=>"214121","ESC"=>"412121","FS"=>"111143","GS"=>"111341","RS"=>"131141","US"=>"114113","FNC 3"=>"114311","FNC 2"=>"411113","SHIFT"=>"411311","CODE C"=>"113141","CODE B"=>"114131","FNC 4"=>"311141","FNC 1"=>"411131","Start A"=>"211412","Start B"=>"211214","Start C"=>"211232","Stop"=>"2331112");
        $code_keys = array_keys($code_array);
        $code_values = array_flip($code_keys);
        for ($X = 1; $X <= strlen($text); $X++) {
            $activeKey = substr( $text, ($X-1), 1);
            $code_string .= $code_array[$activeKey];
            $chksum=($chksum + ($code_values[$activeKey] * $X));
        }
        $code_string .= $code_array[$code_keys[($chksum - (intval($chksum / 103) * 103))]];

        $code_string = "211412" . $code_string . "2331112";
    } elseif ( strtolower($code_type) == "code39" ) {
        $code_array = array("0"=>"111221211","1"=>"211211112","2"=>"112211112","3"=>"212211111","4"=>"111221112","5"=>"211221111","6"=>"112221111","7"=>"111211212","8"=>"211211211","9"=>"112211211","A"=>"211112112","B"=>"112112112","C"=>"212112111","D"=>"111122112","E"=>"211122111","F"=>"112122111","G"=>"111112212","H"=>"211112211","I"=>"112112211","J"=>"111122211","K"=>"211111122","L"=>"112111122","M"=>"212111121","N"=>"111121122","O"=>"211121121","P"=>"112121121","Q"=>"111111222","R"=>"211111221","S"=>"112111221","T"=>"111121221","U"=>"221111112","V"=>"122111112","W"=>"222111111","X"=>"121121112","Y"=>"221121111","Z"=>"122121111","-"=>"121111212","."=>"221111211"," "=>"122111211","$"=>"121212111","/"=>"121211121","+"=>"121112121","%"=>"111212121","*"=>"121121211");

        // Convert to uppercase
        $upper_text = strtoupper($text);

        for ($X = 1; $X <= strlen($upper_text); $X++) {
            $code_string .= $code_array[substr( $upper_text, ($X - 1), 1)] . "1";
        }

        $code_string = "1211212111" . $code_string . "121121211";
    } elseif (strtolower($code_type) == "code25" ) {
        $code_array1 = array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0");
        $code_array2 = array("3-1-1-1-3","1-3-1-1-3","3-3-1-1-1","1-1-3-1-3","3-1-3-1-1","1-3-3-1-1","1-1-1-3-3","3-1-1-3-1","1-3-1-3-1","1-1-3-3-1");

        for ($X = 1; $X <= strlen($text); $X++) {
            for ( $Y = 0; $Y < count($code_array1); $Y++) {
                if (substr($text, ($X-1), 1) == $code_array1[$Y])
                    $temp[$X] = $code_array2[$Y];
            }
        }

        for ($X = 1; $X <= strlen($text); $X += 2) {
            if ( isset($temp[$X]) && isset($temp[($X + 1)])) {
                $temp1 = explode( "-", $temp[$X]);
                $temp2 = explode( "-", $temp[($X + 1)]);
                for ( $Y = 0; $Y < count($temp1); $Y++)
                    $code_string .= $temp1[$Y] . $temp2[$Y];
            }
        }

        $code_string = "1111" . $code_string . "311";
    } elseif (strtolower($code_type) == "codabar") {
        $code_array1 = array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0","-","$",":","/",".","+","A","B","C","D");
        $code_array2 = array("1111221","1112112","2211111","1121121","2111121","1211112","1211211","1221111","2112111","1111122","1112211","1122111","2111212","2121112","2121211","1121212","1122121","1212112","1112122","1112221");

        // Convert to uppercase
        $upper_text = strtoupper($text);

        for ($X = 1; $X <= strlen($upper_text); $X++) {
            for  $Y = 0; $Y<count($code_array1); $Y++) {
                if (substr($upper_text, ($X-1), 1) == $code_array1[$Y])
                    $code_string .= $code_array2[$Y] . "1";
            }
        }
        $code_string = "11221211" . $code_string . "1122121";
    }

    // Pad the edges of the barcode
    $code_length = 20;
    if ($print) {
        $text_height = 30;
    } else {
        $text_height = 0;
    }

    for ($i = 1; $i <= strlen($code_string); $i++) {
        $code_length = $code_length + (integer)(substr($code_string,($i-1),1));
    }

    if (strtolower($orientation) == "horizontal") {
        $img_width = $code_length * $SizeFactor;
        $img_height = $size;
    } else {
        $img_width = $size;
        $img_height = $code_length * $SizeFactor;
    }

    $image = imagecreate($img_width, $img_height + $text_height);
    $black = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
    $white = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);

    imagefill($image, 0, 0, $white);
    if ($print) {
        imagestring($image, 5, 31, $img_height, $text, $black);
    }

    $location = 10;
    for ($position = 1; $position <= strlen($code_string); $position++) {
        $cur_size = $location + (substr($code_string, ($position-1), 1) );
        if (strtolower($orientation) == "horizontal")
            imagefilledrectangle($image, $location*$SizeFactor, 0, $cur_size * $SizeFactor, $img_height, ($position % 2 == 0 ? $white : $black) );
        else
            imagefilledrectangle( $image, 0, $location*$SizeFactor, $img_width, $cur_size*$SizeFactor, ($position % 2 == 0 ? $white : $black) );
        $location = $cur_size;
    }

    // Draw barcode to the screen or save in a file

    header ('Content-type: image/png');
    imagepng($image).'<br>';

    imagedestroy($image);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создаём генератор баркода:

```
$generator = new \Picqer\Barcode\BarcodeGeneratorPNG();
```

Создаём `png-баркод`:

```
$barcode = \base64_encode($generator->getBarcode( 'barcode_date', $generator::TYPE_CODE_128));
```

Добавляем баркод в таблицу:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $insert .= "
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <img src="data:image/png;base64,$barcode" alt="barcode">
            </td>
        </tr>";
}
```

Выводим таблицу:

```
echo "<table>$insert</table>";
```

Используемый [пакет](https://packagist.org/packages/picqer/php-barcode-generator).